# exponentiating x-axis (but not the logged linear relationship) in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on charted predicted probabilities from a mixed effects logit model with a cross-level interaction in ggplot2. I calculated the predicted probabilities and was able to plot the small interaction observed from the models.

[image: The working example]

What I would like to do, if it all possible with `ggplot2` (I'm sure it is) is transform the x-axis there to the original (i.e. exponentiated) scale. The x variable in my working example (`rangeofx`) is the logged and centered values of x from my model. But, I don't want to simply exponentiate the relationship because it would be non-linear and that wasn't what was estimated in the model. I included the un-transformed x values in the working example (`untransformedx`).

How do I do this with the `ggplot2` package? All else equal, I'd be fine with presenting something like this (perhaps adding a legend and making those lines more readable in black and white) and making the reader follow along, but reviewers in my discipline tend to hate that cavalier attitude and would want to see the unintuitive centered-logged values of x correspond with the more intuitive values that are bounded between 0 and 100. This would be appropriate if I wanted to communicate predicted probabilities at untransformed values like 5, 10, 25, 50, 75, and so on. That'll be the next thing I want to do.

Any help here would be appreciated. Working example follows. Thanks.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

Example <- read.csv("http://dl.dropbox.com/s/jyxdo6jgzf72yn5/ggplot2-example.csv")
summary(Example)

ExampleGraph <- ggplot(Example, aes(rangeofx, p.group1)) + geom_line() +
    geom_line(aes(rangeofx, p.group2), color="red") +
    geom_line(aes(rangeofx, p.group3), color="blue") +
    theme_bw() + opts(title="The Effect of X on Y \n Among the Three Groups") + xlab("Range of X (Logged)") + ylab("Pr(Y)")

ggsave(file = "output.png")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `scale_x_sqrt` on `untransformedx`:

```
# transforming your data from wide to long
require(reshape2)
ex2 <- melt(Example, id=c("rangeofx","untransformedx"))

# creating the plot
ggplot(ex2, aes(x=untransformedx, y=value, color=variable)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_sqrt(breaks=c(1,5,10,25,50,75)) +
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(title="The Interaction between X and Y \n Among the Three Groups", x="Range of X (Logged)", y="Pr(Y)")
```

the result:
[image]

Or without adjusting the x-axis:

```
ggplot(ex2, aes(x=untransformedx, y=value, color=variable)) + 
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(title="The Interaction between X and Y \n Among the Three Groups", x="Range of X (Logged)", y="Pr(Y)")
```

which gives:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. How would you add markers at, for example, 1, 5, 10, 25, 50, and 75 for each of the three groups (e.g. diamond for group 1, square for group 2, circle for group 3)?

I didn't think that `scale_x_sqrt` would be the answer. Combined with Paulo's help, I think I should be good going forward. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand what you want with exponentiation of your x var but for the rest
try

```
library(reshape2)

dat <- melt(Example, id = c('rangeofx', 'untransformedx'),
            variable.name = "group")
ggplot(dat, aes(rangeofx, value)) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour = group)) +
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(title="The Interaction between X and Y \n Among the Three Groups", 
       x = "Range of X (Logged)", y ="Pr(Y)") +
  scale_colour_grey()
```

[image: ggplot example with labels]

or with untransformed x variable

```
ggplot(dat, aes(untransformedx, value)) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour = group)) +
  scale_x_sqrt() +
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(title="The Interaction between X and Y \n Among the Three Groups", 
       x = "Range of X (Logged)", y ="Pr(Y)") +
  scale_colour_grey()
```

[image: untransformed x]

Comment: Thanks for showing how to add the legend. This has been helpful to start.

On the exponentiation, it's not that I particularly care about it but I suspect a cranky reviewer would. The `x` variable I estimate in my model is centered and logged (largely because of positive skew and unintuitive/non-occurring zero). However, values of, say, 5, 10, 25, 50, 75 (and so on) are intuitive for a reviewer in my field who may not understand natural logs. I hope that clarifies it a bit.